# Putting user input into a certain point in an array index

Tags: java, arrays

I'm trying to get user input from the HockeyPlayer constructor in the HockeyPlayer class to store in an array in my HockeyPlayerMain class in the array "players". Whenever they press "A" it will call the constructor and if they enter in the number #6, I need to put the object/instance in the array index #5 but i'm not sure how to do this, very beginner with arrays.

Sorry if this is not clear, but I can try to clear things up.

```
package hockeyplayer;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class HockeyPlayer {

private String[] opponent = new String[10];
private int[] goalsScored = new int[10];
private int[] gameNumber = new int[10];
private String name;
private int playerNumber;
private int gameNum;

public HockeyPlayer() {

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("What is the name of the player?");
    name = input.nextLine();
    System.out.println("What is the player's number?");
    playerNumber = input.nextInt();
    input.nextLine();

}


public String[] getOpponent() {
    return opponent;
}

public void setOpponent(String[] opponent) {
    this.opponent = opponent;
}

public int[] getGoalsScored() {
    return goalsScored;
}

public void setGoalsScored(int[] goalsScored) {
    this.goalsScored = goalsScored;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public int getPlayerNumber() {
    return playerNumber;
}

public void setPlayerNumber(int playerNumber) {
    this.playerNumber = playerNumber;
}

public void addGameDetails(){
    HockeyPlayer player1 = new HockeyPlayer();

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("What game number was it?");
    gameNumber[0] = input.nextInt();
    input.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Who were the opponents?");
    opponent[0] = input.nextLine();
    System.out.println("How many goals did the player score?");
    goalsScored[0] = input.nextInt();

}

}

package hockeyplayer;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class HockeyMain {

private static String choice;
private static HockeyPlayer[] players = new HockeyPlayer[12];
private static final String MENU = "Hockey Tracker\n"+
        "A-Add Player\n"+
        "G-Add game details\n"+
        "S-Show players\n"+
        "X-Quit\n";

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);


 do{    
    System.out.println(MENU);
    choice = input.nextLine();

    switch(choice){
        case "A":
           for(int i = 0; i < players.length; ++i){
            players[i] = new HockeyPlayer();
    }
            break;
        case "G":

            break;
        case "S":
            break;
        case "X":    
     }

}while(!choice.equals("X"));   
}



}
```

Comment: Do you mean that the number given in the `HockerPlayer` constructor should be the index of the player in the array inside `HockeyMain` class?

Comment: BTW whole logic looks quite "strange", but answer from @Maciej Kowalski is correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this in your for loop:

```
for(int i = 0; i < players.length; ++i){
        HockeyPlayer player = new HockeyPlayer();    
        players[player.getPlayerNmumber()] = player; 
    }
```

If you want to enter just one player at a time the 'A' option is pressed, then you simply remove the for loop:

```
switch(choice){
    case "A":
        HockeyPlayer p = new HockeyPlayer();
        players[p.getPlayerNumber()] = p;
        break;
    case "G":

        break;
    case "S":
        break;
    case "X":    
 }
```

Comment: Yeah this is what I was trying to do, thanks. I tried this earlier but I might of typed it wrong.

Comment: What if I didn't want to do it all 12 at once? Like just one player at a time then it goes back to the menu?

Comment: Please see the post. I have added that scenario

Comment: If the post fixes your problems, then i would appreciate if you could accept it. Thanks

Comment: How would I get the instance from the case "A" down to case "G"? I can't move the instance because it adds a player, while case "G" i want to edit the player.

Answer (score 1):

Im not sure if that is what you mean but you could use the `getPlayerNumber()` method in the `HockeyMain` class. This can cause overwriting in the array if the user input is not correct which means the array will not be filled completely.

```
do{    
System.out.println(MENU);
choice = input.nextLine();

switch(choice){
    case "A":
       for(int i = 0; i < players.length; ++i){
        HockeyPlayer p = new HockeyPlayer();
        players[p.getPlayerNumber()] = p;
       }
        break;
    case "G":

        break;
    case "S":
        break;
    case "X":    
 }
}while(!choice.equals("X"));
```